# How to disable ClickOnce security in windows c# form?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, clickonce

Hey i just made my c# program which needs admin privilages to access certain files, but while publishing the application it shows a build error ("clickonce does not support require administrator"), i have tried disabling the checkbox of clickonce but however it still gets enabled. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, is there any update in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this article that led me to a solution to problem. Hope it can help you.
https://www.codeproject.com/tips/627850/clickonce-deployment-vs-requestedexecutionlevel-eq

You leave your manifest as is:

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />`

Add code in Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        var wp = new WindowsPrincipal(wi);

        bool runAsAdmin = wp.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);

        if (!runAsAdmin)
        {
            // It is not possible to launch a ClickOnce app as administrator directly,
            // so instead we launch the app as administrator in a new process.
            var processInfo = 
                new ProcessStartInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

            // The following properties run the new process as administrator
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            processInfo.Verb = "runas";

            // Start the new process
            try
            {
                Process.Start(processInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // The user did not allow the application to run as administrator
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, but I don't seem to be able to start " + 
                   "this program with administrator rights!");
            }

            // Shut down the current process
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            // We are running as administrator
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```